# nodemon not starting when run in kubernetes environment

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, google-kubernetes-engine, nodemon

I am working on containerizing a nodejs app to be running on GKE.
the scripts section of package.json looks like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:build-server dev:build-client  dev:server",
    "dev:server": "nodemon -L --watch build --exec node build/bundle.js",
    "dev:build-server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch",
    "dev:build-client": "webpack --config webpack.client.js --watch"
  },
```

so when running im using `npm run dev` to start them all.

this works perfectly while it is running on VM.
But when run as a container in kubernetes the nodemon process won't start.
nor it listens on the port. it gives a 502 status error on browser

but when you ssh to the pod and try running the command it starts the process.listens on 3001 port but obviously it gives routes not found on browser. since they are not linked as expected.

below is the dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.19-stretch
ENV USER="vue" UID="1001"


RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -yq curl
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    mkdir -p /opt/vue && \
    addgroup --system -gid $UID $USER && \
    adduser --system --uid $UID --gid $UID $USER

WORKDIR /opt/vue

COPY dashboard/. /opt/vue/


RUN npm cache clean --force && \
    npm install  && \
    npm cache verify  && \
    chown $USER.$USER -R /opt/vue

USER $USER
EXPOSE 3001
# ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init","--"]
# CMD ["npm run dev"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

tried using base images (`node:10.19-stretch,node:10.19.0-alpine3.11`)
some had sugested installing inotify but even that didn't work.
what am I missing. please help.

UPDATE ---

when run either in docker or kubernetes standerout log says this
with no errors(enabled verbose output)

```
[nodemon] Looking in package.json for nodemonConfig
  Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args]

  See "nodemon --help" for more.

[nodemon] exiting
```

Comment: What does the docker log say when starting up the container?

Comment: @eol didnt run this on docker. ran it directly on kubrnetes. no errors on kubernetes logs

Comment: Ok, but do you see a success message like `[nodemon] starting <your-script.js>` or is there no output at all?

Comment: no output from nodemon...
when its run on vm it shows listening on port 3001 and nodemon version etc. out put.
but in kubernetes there's nothing. all other processes are stating successfully

Comment: Can you provide exact steps for running it in a VM instance ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B yeah. 
npm install ;
npm run dev ; ( this sticks to shell. once the shell  is closed it shuts down. so im sending it to background via nohup)

Comment: @eol ive added the output of nodemon as a update to the post

Answer (score 0):

after some peer reviewing and posting this on other networks found the correct answer.

issue behind was obvious.
in the scripts section the all dev:* scripts were running parallel. so when the two build steps were running the nodemon service was trying to start the service. and since the build/bundle.json is not there it gives a file not found. but the nodemon thinks of it as invalid arguments and gives the command help.

so what I did was adding the build steps in the docker file by running

```
npm run dev
```

and then on the CMD adding the

```
npm run prod:server
```

which actually speeded up the startupt time too.

here is the dockerfile part that was changed.

```
RUN npm cache clean --force && \
    npm install  && \
    npm cache verify  && \
    chown $USER.$USER -R /opt/vue

USER $USER
EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "run", "prod:server" ]
```

also I had removed nodemon as its not needed. since files will not be changed anyway and they are too bulky

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:build-server dev:build-client",
    "prod:server": "node build/bundle.js",
    "dev:build-server": "webpack --config webpack.server.js --watch",
    "dev:build-client": "webpack --config webpack.client.js --watch"
  },
```

finally.. !! viola.. it worked.

Thanks everyone who put their precious time on this.

Comment: pm2 runtime is recommended when running nodejs applications

Comment: yeah. your point is valid when its run on VMs or baremetal servers. BUt when it comes to containers we should think of the valuble resources. in that aspect even pm2, nodemon, and many other unwanted libs should be removed to save resources.
anyway we may not  need to reload nodemon for file changes in the containers right. as they are not changed. if neededs a chang it has to be done through separate deployment.
what do you think @LakinduAkash

Comment: For the production environment pm2 is very lightweight as I know and from the experience. Yes, nodemon is of course can be removed and setup as dev dependency. When you run npm install --only=prod, it will only install limited packages declared under dependency list.

Comment: And, yes changing file means new docker image in most cases unless your application has no specific requirement to detect live changes. Typical ci/cd pipeline detect the code changes and build a new docker image and deploy the new version.